# WPF textblock, mixing of foreground color

Tags: wpf, textblock, foreground

In WPF textblock, how do I make the content inside the text having different colors.

```
<Label FontSize="32" Foreground="White">
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Player 1 just win XXX Game from CK." />
</Label>
```

For example, the whole sentences is in white color, but I need "Player 1" and "CK" to be in different color, can WPF do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that using [Inlines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.inlines.aspx)

```
<TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap">
     <TextBlock.Inlines>
         <Run Foreground="Red" Text="Player 1"/>
         <Run Foreground="White" Text=" just win XXX Game from"/>
         <Run Foreground="Green" Text=" CK" />
     </TextBlock.Inlines>
</TextBlock>
```